# Delphi - Hidden MDI child form creation

Tags: delphi, forms, mdi

My application has many many mdi forms and they are created after successfull user login. How can I best hide this creation process? It looks stupid and it takes longer time while mdi forms are painted after new form is created and so on.

So far I have used LockWindowUpdate, which doesn't hide everything, but I would like to use a splash screen showing the creation progress, but I can't with LockWindowUpdate.

Best Regards
  Janne

Comment: Don't create them at startup. Create them when you need them.

Comment: How the avoid the painting of a hidden child window info in the menu windows list ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create MDI child forms invisible you set their `Visible` property to `False`, and in addition you have to disable the VCL behaviour of force-showing them during creation. This happens by the `FormStyle` property setter of `TCustomForm`, which sets `Visible` to `True` for MDI child forms.

If you set the `FormStyle` in the object inspector, then the property setter will be called during form creation already, and the form will not be shown immediately, but only after the construction is complete. This allows you to reset the request to show the form, by overriding the `AfterConstruction()` method like so:

```
procedure TMDIChild.AfterConstruction;
begin
  Exclude(FFormState, fsVisible);
  inherited;
end;
```

This will create an invisible MDI child form.

To test this you can create a new MDI application in the IDE, override the method in the child form class like shown above, and simulate a long initialization:

```
procedure TMainForm.FileNew1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do begin
    CreateMDIChild('NONAME' + IntToStr(MDIChildCount + 1));
    Update;
    Sleep(500);
  end;
  for i := 0 to MDIChildCount - 1 do
    MDIChildren[i].Visible := True;
end;
```

Without the overridden `AfterConstruction()` method it will create and show a MDI child every half second. With the overridden method it will show them all after a busy period of 5 seconds, which will give you the chance to show your splash screen instead.

**Important:**

Using [`LockWindowUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145034%28VS.85%29.aspx) to reduce flicker or suppress any screen output is wrong, wrong, wrong. [Don't do it](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/22/1742084.aspx), read the series of [Raymond Chen articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/22/1742084.aspx) on the topic to understand why that is so.

Comment: +1 for a very tidy, Delphi only way of doing this. I have normally had to resort to the Win API (ShowWindow) to achieve this.

Comment: Excellent! This was exactly what I was looking for and with Raymond Chen tips I could disable the redraw for visible := true loop.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with flickering MDI childs. I used combination of overrinding **AfterConstruction** and **WM_SETREDRAW** message from this tip: 
[Controlling the placement of fsMDIChild windows in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507144/controlling-the-placement-of-fsmdichild-windows-in-delphi)

```
SendMessage(Application.MainForm.ClientHandle, WM_SETREDRAW, False, 0);
try
  Child := TChildForm.Create(Self);
  Child.Left := ...;
  Child.Top := ...;
  Child.Show;
finally
  SendMessage(Application.MainForm.ClientHandle, WM_SETREDRAW, True, 0);
  InvalidateRect(Application.MainForm.ClientHandle, nil, True);
end;
```

And everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it's work for me

```
 try
  SendMessage(Application.MainForm.ClientHandle,WM_SETREDRAW,0,0);
  FormChild:=TBaseChildForm.Create(application);
  FormChild.Caption:='Form '+IntToStr(n);
  FormChild.Show;
 finally
  SendMessage(Application.MainForm.ClientHandle,WM_SETREDRAW,1,0);
  RedrawWindow(Application.MainForm.ClientHandle, nil, 0, RDW_FRAME or RDW_INVALIDATE or   RDW_ALLCHILDREN or RDW_NOINTERNALPAINT);
 end;
```