# OnShow-Event while Construction?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a Form (**fsMDIChild**). This is inside the OnShow-Event of `TForm4.FormShow`:

```
if targetDatabase.hasItems then
```

**Unfortunately** OnShow is called indirectly on instantiation:

```
  program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2},
  Unit3 in 'Unit3.pas' {Form3},
  Unit4 in 'Unit4.pas' {Form4};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm3, Form3);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm4, Form4); // <-- calls TForm4.OnShow! Why?
  Application.Run;
end.
```

I put a Breakpoint inside fo the ShowForm-Handler. This is the Output of my Stack-View:

- TForm4.FormShow(???)
- Project1

My Question is:

- Why is OnShow called on an fsMDIChild?

Comment: Id expected to have OnCreate-Event called, ok but OnShow?

Comment: You might find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2683667/1699210) a workaround for the standard behavior of a MDIChild. Usually you will create the form a runtime if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the normal way of things, for standard forms, you would not expect this to happen. So clearly there is some code in your project that triggers this behaviour.

As some general advice, you can use the debugger to find out why this happens.

1. In the project options, check the *Debug DCUs* option.
2. Set a breakpoint in your `OnShow` event handler.
3. Run the program under the debugger.
4. When the breakpoint fires inspect the call stack.

By enabling debug DCUs you ensure that you will get a complete call stack including functions in the VCL. Follow the call stack to work out why the event is firing.

Now, the extra specific information is that the form in question is an MDI child. They cannot be made invisible, and so are shown immediately. In other words, the behaviour that you observe is expected. MDI children are always visible. Hence the `OnShow` event fires during construction.

Comment: I make a breakpoint at `Application.CreateForm(TForm4, Form4);` and *step-in* using F7 and am **right** inside the `FormShow`-Procedure!

Comment: I had a Breakpoint in the `OnShow`-Event (namely `ShowForm`), see the Quesion.

Comment: Did you enable debug dcus? See my answer.

Comment: Great hint, ill try this.

Comment: OK, it's an MDI child form. They are always visible.

Comment: That's just how the MDI system works. MDI child windows cannot be invisible. Why are you creating so many forms anyway? I just create them when I want to show them. And they should be given better names.

Comment: In fact they have better names. To use names like Form1-Form4 helps to understand the questions, so i only follow the rule: *dont let me think*. Even the Stacktrace is imaginary. After all your critic about the naming is correct but more related to codereview-site.

Comment: @Peter that's fine. Remember that I don't know that and wrote my comment based on what I could see.