# Setting FormStyle as MDIChild without showing it

Tags: forms, delphi, visibility, mdi, mdichild

My application has several MDI forms. I would like to set their FormStyle property to fsMDIChild without showing them. Unfortunately, FormStyle setter makes form visible if its value is fsMDIChild.

```
procedure TCustomForm.SetFormStyle(Value: TFormStyle);
const
  HWND_STYLE: array[Boolean] of HWND = (HWND_NOTOPMOST, HWND_TOPMOST);
var
  OldStyle: TFormStyle;
  LRecreate: Boolean;
begin
  if FFormStyle <> Value then
  begin
    if ((Value = fsNormal) and (FFormStyle = fsStayOnTop)) or
       ((Value = fsStayOnTop) and (FFormStyle = fsNormal)) then
    begin
      FFormStyle := Value;
      if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) and HandleAllocated then
        SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_STYLE[FFormStyle = fsStayOnTop], 0, 0, 0, 0,
          SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
    end
    else
    begin
      if (Value = fsMDIChild) and (Position = poDesigned) then
        Position := poDefault;
      LRecreate := not (csDesigning in ComponentState);
      if LRecreate then
        UpdateRecreatingFlag(True);
      try
        if LRecreate then DestroyHandle;
        OldStyle := FFormStyle;
        FFormStyle := Value;
        if ((Value = fsMDIForm) or (OldStyle = fsMDIForm)) and not Ctl3d then
          Color := NormalColor;
        if LRecreate then UpdateControlState;
        if Value = fsMDIChild then Visible := True;
      finally
        if LRecreate then
          UpdateRecreatingFlag(False);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I have seen this question [Delphi - Hidden MDI child form creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682841/delphi-hidden-mdi-child-form-creation), but the answer imply that FormStyle is set by using the object inspector and is created as fsMDIChild.

Comment: You cannot hide an MDI child window. This is a Win32 limitation.

Comment: Instead of hide simply close/destroy the child form.